# apt upgrade configuration difference exit

Tags: apt, upgrade, configuration

I ran Apt update and upgrade and I get a prompt that one of the configuration files are different. I typed 'D' and reviewed the file and decided I want to keep my version. However I can't find how to exit the review page. I can scroll up and down but have no idea how to actually exit the preview, I reviewed the Manual page in a separate terminal window but it didn't mention anything.

How does one exit the previewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the viewer presented, Q or Esc will get you back.

If the diff is presented in a text window on the console, try Tab to go the button at the bottom, then hit Enter to press it.